# Program that changes PID every n seconds

Tags: c

I'm new to system programming in C.

Here I'm trying to write a program that changes its PID every (n=2) seconds. But while compiling, I get every time, the same PID. The PID never changes. Does anyone have an idea please ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

printf("Programme qui change de PID toutes les deux secondes \n");
pid_t fils;

while(1){
    printf("I'm %d\n",(int)getpid());
    sleep(5);
    fils = fork();
    if(fils < 0){
        perror("Fork child \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (fils ==0 )
        exit(0); 

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `else if (fils ==0 )` to `else if (fils > 0 )`. Your code as shown exits the child process and leaves the same/first parent process running. Since it is the same process of course its pid remains the same.

Comment: @kaylum, it works! Thank you :)

Comment: Minor nit pick: The canonical way to express a non-terminating loop in C is `for(;;)` as it avoids the constant value boolean in the `while(1)` condition (some lints complain about it). And it's shorter to type!

Comment: @Jens : Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: @Jens: `while(true)` is entirely idiomatic C.

Comment: @EOF I happen to disagree for several reasons. a) K&R never used it in the best book on C, "The C Programming Language" (1st and 2nd ed). b) `true` became a part of C not until 1999. c) It draws warnings from some lints. d) It's longer than necessary. Anything called idiomatic should not have any of those issues.

Comment: @Jens: It's bikeshedding. The loop is immediately recognizable as an infinite loop (barring `break` or `goto`) by anyone with even a cursory knowledge of C. It's fine.

Comment: @EOF We just happen to have different criteria for *idiomatic*, which is OK. I do enjoy a worthy bike shed every now and then. :-)

Comment: @Jens: Well, if your criterion for idiomatic is K&R, I suppose you also like old-style function declarations better than prototypes.

Answer (score 3):

the reason the PID is not changing is because a process pid never changes.  and the code is always in the parent process when checking the value of the PID.

Now, each child process will receive its' own PID.  You could be having the child get/display its' PID before exiting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
else if (fils ==0 ){
    //<- here
    //printf("my pid is %d\n", getpid());
           exit(0);  
}
```

is the scope of the new process you have forked off.

You can think of this scope as a `main` of its own and it is this scope that will run in a different process with its own `pid`.

(You probably want `_exit` rather then `exit` there to preven double-flushing of `stdio` buffers. (The child process gets a copy))

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)